# Directory / folder path?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I am Trying to upgrade from 2.3.0 -> 2.3.1

This issue began as I'm trying to add my logo to the top of emails and have been told the upgrade has a fix to the bug.

i am used the luma theme.

Error message I receive after inputting access keys :

> Invalid response line returned from server: HTTP/2 401

I've been advised to create a `curl.php` file and save it to

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

I don't have this directory / folder path mine is I don't have this path on my system, mine is lib/internal{GnuFreeFont / LinLibertineFont}.

Do I create the folder path?

Please advise on this..

Comment: how you are upgrading the Magento version by CLI or by admin?

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade using admin